# Transparent png become blackish when changing to MTLTexture

Tags: swift, metal, metalkit

I am changing png format which is in the Asset folder to MTLTexture. It is becoming blackish in the transparent edges.

```
 func loadTexture(device: MTLDevice, textureName: String) throws -> MTLTexture {
        let textureLoader = MTKTextureLoader(device: device)
        return try textureLoader.newTexture(name: textureName, scaleFactor: 1.0, bundle: nil,  options: nil)
    }
```

The pipeline Descriptor is

```
  let pipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
        pipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentFunction
        pipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexFunction
        pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
        pipelineDescriptor.sampleCount = 4

        pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].isBlendingEnabled = true
        pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation = .add
        pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].alphaBlendOperation = .add
        pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .one
        pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .one
        pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
        pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
```

Comment: This probably has to do with [not using premultiplied alpha](http://www.realtimerendering.com/blog/gpus-prefer-premultiplication/), but it would *really* help to have a screenshot to diagnose the issue.

Comment: https://github.com/PIRANAVARUBAN/Texture

Comment: @warrenm I added my code you can go through it

Comment: It's almost like you're configuring blending on the wrong pipeline descriptor. If I configure the pipeline descriptor that's actually being used (in MetalLineDrawingView.swift) with the parameters you provided, I get good-looking results. Are you sure you're not configuring/using the wrong pipeline descriptor/state?

Comment: @Ruban4Axis, Provide us with your PNG image and a screenshot of the result.